# Do react render props cause remounting of the child components?

Tags: reactjs

I was just wondering if people know if using the "render props" pattern causes excessive mounting/unmounting of the child component. 
For example, adapting from the react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html):

```
<Mouse>
{mouse => (
    <ShowMousePosition mouse={mouse}/>
  )}
</Mouse>


class ShowMousePosition extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('mounting!')
  }
  render () {
    const {mouse} = this.props
    return (
      <p>The mouse position is {mouse.x}, {mouse.y}</p>
    )
  }
}
```

I know the react docs say:

> Using a render prop can negate the advantage that comes from using React.PureComponent if you create the function inside a render method. This is because the shallow prop comparison will always return false for new props, and each render in this case will generate a new value for the render prop.

But, will "mounting!" be called over and over as the user moves the mouse around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I went ahead and tried to answer my own question using a fiddle. It appears that "mounting!" is not called over and over again:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/186690/

Here is the code:

```jsx
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Mouse>
   {mouse => (
       <ShowMousePosition mouse={mouse}/>
     )}
   </Mouse>
  }
}

class Mouse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  handleMouseMove(event) {
    this.setState({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 800, width: 800 }} onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>

        {/*
          Instead of providing a static representation of what <Mouse> renders,
          use the `render` prop to dynamically determine what to render.
        */}
        {this.props.children(this.state)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}




   class ShowMousePosition extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('mountin!')
  }
  render () {
    const {mouse} = this.props
    return (
      <p>The mouse position is {mouse.x}, {mouse.y}</p>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount is only called once but componentDidUpdate will be called multiple times along with your render function every time your state/props is changed.